# How to show that we can't use the negative root in $e^x$ = $y\pm\sqrt{y^2+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

We have that $e^x$ = $y\pm\sqrt{y^2+1}$ but we know that $e^x$ > 0 so we must use $e^x$ = $y+\sqrt{y^2+1}$; how do I show that $y-\sqrt{y^2+1}$ will always be $\le 0$?

Answer (score 2):

First show that $y^2 < y^2+1$.  Then $y < \sqrt{y^2+1}$, so $y-\sqrt{y^2+1} < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$ y^2<y^2+1\implies  y<\sqrt{y^2+1}\implies y-\sqrt{y^2+1}<0$